# How to specify all three images to show when a page is shared on LinkedIn?

Tags: images, meta-tags, open-graph-protocol, linkedin

When you share a URL on LinkedIn, it shows three images from that page.  How can I get it to show the correct three images to the person posting when they paste my company URL into a post?

I've tried using the open graph meta tags, but that only allows me to specify one of the three images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Open Graph standard's `<meta>` tags in the `<head>` of your HTML page. Like so:

```
<html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
<head>
  <meta property="og:title" content="My Shared Article Title" />
  <meta property="og:description" content="Description of shared article" />
  <meta property="og:url" content="http://example.com/my_article.html" />
  <meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/foo.jpg" />
</head>
<body>
   …
</body>
</html>
```

For further read, check out documentation: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin

Comment: Thats what i do, and it makes linkedin suggest 1 good image, but then it chooses 2 bad ones at random.  How can i get all 3 image options set? The open graph only has 1 meta tag for 1 image, right?

Comment: @fandang, just put three og:image meta tegs

Comment: thanks @Maxim Mazurok - I tried that at: http://www.puzzlesforfriends.com/w/tc/7.html, but when I share that link on linkedin, it still shows the same 3 it had been showing before.  Do a view-source, and you'll see my 3 og:image meta tags....thoughts?

Comment: @fandang, you should use an image that's at least 200x200px. Also you can debug your open graph tags by yourself here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/

Comment: thanks again :) but still no go - I put it at http://techconnect.thinkinghuge.com/2.html now.  That FB link you gave me was great, and it sees all 3 images I want to show, but then when I paste the link to that 2.html on linkedin.com, it still shows the old images, not the ones FB says  it should show.  I keep changing the  name of the file to prevent linkedin from caching it, so I dont think that's the problem....thoughts?

Comment: @fandang well, i hope when we will solve the problem, you will thank we by upvoting or selecting answer as good answer :)
First, you should use `itemscope` attribute in `html` tag without `=""` as it is boolean value.
Second, you should use `prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#"` instead of `xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"`, as it is the new recommended way. Let me know if it worked for you.